# Laravel routes do not work

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am still new to PHP Laravel framework. The problem is that my Laravel routes do not work. Here is the simple code of my routes.php:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function()
{
return View::make('hello'); //shows "Hello" page
});

Route::get('somepage', function()
{
    return View::make('somepage'); // Apache server shows 404 error
});
```

I have configured my Apache param **AllowOverride All** and the **mod_rewrite** module is loaded. I have another installation of Laravel which works (throws 'NotFound' exception on undeclared route), but this one does not respond properly, on the same server. Where is the problem?

Comment: you tell us the problem! what error it throws?

Comment: try /index.php/somepage

Comment: Yes, deczo, it works. Thank you. So what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your .htaccess file is setup correctly.

http://laravel.com/docs/installation#configuration

Answer (score -1):

Please configure your Apache param AllowOverride All and ensure the mod_rewrite module is loaded.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#pretty-urls